# Get the URL of a Git repo so I can upload my local repo there

Tags: git, github

I want to import a Git repository to Github but do not know how to get the URL via commands, but cannot find a command for it. I am on Windows, using Git Bash.

I tried `git ls-remote --get-url origin` but it did not work.
Any kind of help would be nice. I am not using a remote repo; it is my own I made with `git init`.

Comment: Then how could it have a remote repo with a URL? This makes no sense.

Comment: You need to create a repo on Github and **push** your local code to it. Github even provides instructions specifically for this case when you create the repository. See also https://docs.github.com/en/migrations/importing-source-code/using-the-command-line-to-import-source-code/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github

Comment: When you create a new repo on Github, it tells you how to set it up as the remote for a repo which already exists. In brief, `git add remote origin` (the URL of the Github repo)